# Android form elements have different sizes on different emulators

Tags: android, android-layout

### Update #1

I observed that setting `<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>` as 20sp in /res/values/styles.xml will cause the input elements to appear normally on devices smaller than 5". It seems that reducing the text size did not reduce the size of the input box. Is this supposed to be normal?

### TLDR version

Hi there,

I am facing a problem with the size of input elements in my Android project. The input elements appear larger on devices that are < 5" in size, but appear otherwise normal on my larger devices.

The below screenshots illustrate this. Any idea what could be the cause?

### Detailed version

Hi there,

I am currently facing an odd problem with the size of my form elements in my Android project across different emulators.
As this is the first time I am creating a mobile application, please feel free to enlighten me if this is a "feature", rather than a bug.

On the **Nexus 7** layout preview, the form elements appear as I expected:

[image]

However, on the Galaxy Nexus layout preview, the form elements appear larger than expected, which is not desirable:

[image]

I have tried many methods, but have been unable to resolve this problem. This problem occurs on all devices that are less than 5" in screen size.

Here is my layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_link"
        style="@style/FormFont.Label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickRegisterLink"
        android:text="@string/register_link_text" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_layout_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/register_link"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_form"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_form"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_form"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_username"
                style="@style/FormFont.Label"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label_password"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/label_password"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/input_username"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/label_username" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_password"
                style="@style/FormFont.Label"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_below="@+id/label_username"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/input_password"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/label_passphrase" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_username"
                style="@style/FormFont.Input"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                style="@style/FormFont.Input"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                style="@style/FormFont.Label"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/button_login" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My /res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FormFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FormFont.Label">
    </style>

    <style name="FormFont.Input">
        <item name="android:ems">12</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My /res/values-large/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
    
    <style name="FormFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FormFont.Label">
    </style>

    <style name="FormFont.Input">
        <item name="android:ems">12</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Please let me know if you have encountered this before and have an idea of what could be the cause :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I hope you know that Nexus7's screen size is xlarge? So, apparently, both Nexus7 and Galaxy Nexus are using values from `/res/values/styles.xml` as there is no resources defined at `/res/values-xlarge/styles.xml`

Comment: i have /res/values-large/styles.xml, /res/values-xlarge/styles.xml, /res/values/styles.xml, /res/values-small/styles.xml defined. I am pretty sure Nexus 7 is large because its responding to changes in the large stylesheet.

Comment: I am aiming to find out why the size of the form elements do not scale accordingly in small screens as compared to larger screens.

Comment: OK, I was wrong. `N7 == large` and `GNEX == normal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by specifing a different value for the property `android:layout_height` in `/res/values-xlarge/styles.xml`, `/res/values-large/styles.xml`, `/res/values/styles.xml`, `/res/values-small/styles.xml`.

This allowed me to control the exact height of each input field in Android devices of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that screen density of Galaxy Nexus is `xhdpi`

[image: nexus virtual devices]

You may want to add `res/values-xhdpi/` and add values for devices in Galaxy Nexus-screen-family. You may also play with `sw<N>dp` (for Galaxy Nexus that'd be `res/values-sw320dp/`; *the actual screen dimensions are `360dp X 567dp`, that's, although `values-sw320dp` would include Galaxy Nexus, it will also include any other devices with minimum width/height of 320dp*), `w<N>dp` and/or `h<N>dp`. See the table in [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: I have tried playing with different text size values and failed to resolve the problem. This answer does not solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

> However, on the Galaxy Nexus layout preview, the form elements appear
>   larger than expected, which is not desirable

Actually, it's not bigger. The `EditText` has the exact same physical size on both devices. This is how Density-independent Pixels(dp) work. They will scale everything based on the density baseline, so that everything has the same size across multiple devices. This is especially useful, if you have two devices, that have the same screen size, but different densities. So the physical size of the UI elements on both devices stays the same. If you would have used pixels (px) it would be very different (The physical size of the device with a higher density would be smaller than the one on the lower-density device).

It *appears* bigger, because 1. The UI of both, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7 in the UI editor is scaled to (almost) the same form factor 2. You set different text sizes for both. This is how is actually looks like:

[image]

The `EditTexts` on both devices (The screenshots actually are from my Nexus 4, which has a only slightly higher density than the GN, so it shouldn't be a big problem, and my Nexus 7) have the same height, but the N4 has a smaller text (which is because you specified it to be this way).